# Location and OAuth problems using Twitter search API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm going to tell exactly my homework: Add a twitter search capability to the website. The search should auto update every 20 seconds and carry out searches for the most recent mentions of the hash tag '#EN0700'.

The tweets should be shown in a list with the date, author's username on twitter, and the tweet location data (where the tweet is tweeted).  I tried to use https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/search.json?query=Twitter%20HQ as in the http://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/geo/search example, but it does not display the location result. Is my URL correct?

The other thing is that if I use http://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.json?q=Twitter%20API, I received:

```
"{"error":"Could not authenticate you.","request":"/1/users/search.json?q=EN0745"}"
```

although I have registered my application in the oAUTH. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my class to sign requests https://github.com/andreyknupp/Twitter

```
<?php
      spl_autoload_register ( function ( $class ) {
           require_once sprintf ( '%s.php' , $class ) ;
      } ) ;

      $URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.json';
      $Data = Array ( 'q' => 'Search' ) ;

      $Authentication = new \Twitter\TwitterAuthentication();

      $Authentication->setConsumerKey ( 'UExmB6GoxftjZqdngw' );
      $Authentication->setConsumerSecret ( '1yUvMAnrFiu86vCdhwAqM5ZHsgXRVyNhRdUDxeo' );
      $Authentication->setAccessToken ( '2660353-PjccZS0nO28zaV0xaxR2UBklZR0nkjjso2wmLa' );
      $Authentication->setAccessTokenSecret ( 'DWwLG3RFt1drU0qRc4PHu0wdlmVks08BDM' );

      $OAuth = new Twitter\TwitterOAuthentication( $Authentication );
      $OAuth->setSignatureURL ( $URL . '?' . http_build_query ( $Data , false , '&' ) ) ;
      $OAuth->setSignatureMethod( 'GET' ) ; 

      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_URL ,  $URL . '?' . http_build_query ( $Data , false , '&' ) ) ;
      curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_HEADER , false ) ;
      curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , Array ( $OAuth->buildAuthorization( $Data ) ) ) ;
      curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true ) ;
      curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false );

      $response = json_decode ( curl_exec ( $curl ) ) ;
      print_r ( $response ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best off using a PHP library for this to make things easy. You can find them [here on the Twitter Developers site.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php)